# How to migrate my remoting Channels code from net framework to netcore?

Tags: .net-core, .net-framework-version

I am trying to migrate an application from .net Framework to .Net Core 3.1.
I have encountered the problem that the System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels library is not available for .Net core.

Any way to rewrite the methods by calling another using?

What alternatives are currently available to carry out the same process from .net core?

This is how it was used in net framework:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
using System.Threading;
using Myapp.Infrastructure.Settings;

namespace Myapp.Infrastructure.Messaging
{
    public static class MessagingClient
    {
        private static TcpChannel _channel;
        private static MessagingServerObject _serverObject;
        private static MessagingClientObject _clientObject;
        private static readonly Timer Timer = new Timer(OnTimerTick, null, Timeout.Infinite, 1000);
        private static IMessageListener _messageListener;

        public static bool IsConnected { get; set; }

        private static void OnTimerTick(object state)
        {
            if (_clientObject != null && _messageListener != null && IsConnected)
            {
                string[] arrData;
                _clientObject.GetData(out arrData);

                foreach (var t in arrData.Distinct())
                {
                    _messageListener.ProcessMessage(t);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            if (!IsConnected) return;
            Timer.Dispose();
            Disconnect();
        }

        public static void Disconnect()
        {
            IsConnected = false;
            _messageListener = null;
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    if (_serverObject != null)
                        _serverObject.Detach(_clientObject);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    _serverObject = null;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_channel != null)
                {
                    ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(_channel);
                    _channel = null;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            if (_serverObject != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _serverObject.SetValue(string.Format("{0}", message));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    if (IsConnected) Disconnect();
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool CanPing()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_serverObject != null)
                {
                    _serverObject.Ping();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (IsConnected) Disconnect();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static void Reconnect(IMessageListener messageListener)
        {
            try
            {
                Disconnect();
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
            }
            _messageListener = messageListener;
            Connect(_messageListener);
        }

        public static void Connect(IMessageListener messageListener)
        {
            Timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
            if (messageListener == null) return;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LocalSettings.MessagingServerName)) return;

            _messageListener = messageListener;
            var serverProv = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider
                                 {
                                     TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full
                                 };

            var clientProv = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();

            IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
            props["port"] = 0;

            _channel = new TcpChannel(props, clientProv, serverProv);

            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(_channel, false);

            var url = String.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}/ChatServer", LocalSettings.MessagingServerName, LocalSettings.MessagingServerPort);

            try
            {
                _serverObject = (MessagingServerObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(MessagingServerObject), url);
                _clientObject = new MessagingClientObject();
                _serverObject.Attach(_clientObject);
            }
            catch
            {
                HandleError();
                return;
            }
            IsConnected = true;
            Timer.Change(0, 1000);
        }

        private static void HandleError()
        {
            _messageListener = null;
            _serverObject = null;
            _clientObject = null;
            if (_channel != null)
            {
                ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(_channel);
                _channel = null;
            }
            IsConnected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The MS docs indicate some potential replacements under "Remoting": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable

Comment: Thanks @EvanTrimboli Do you know any tutorial to help me migrate? Any help will be helpful